# received plaintext http traffic on an https channel, closing connection Netty4HttpChannel{localAddress=/127.0.0.1:9200, remoteAddress=/127.0.0.1:494

Tags: elasticsearch, connection

I am trying to run elasticsearch cluster on my local machine, I have downloaded java, elasticsearch, and Kibana.
From elasticsearch directory I did `bin/elasticsearch`
then a log on the terminal start to appear and says the status is green, but when I visit `http://127.0.0.1:9300/` its says can no connection
Below is part of the terminal log where I think is the error:

```
[2022-02-18T15:50:28,173][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService] [Yusufs-MBP.home] current.health="GREEN" message="Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [GREEN] (reason: [shards started [[.geoip_databases][0], [.security-7][0]]])." previous.health="RED" reason="shards started [[.geoip_databases][0], [.security-7][0]]"
[2022-02-18T15:50:28,492][INFO ][o.e.i.g.DatabaseNodeService] [Yusufs-MBP.home] successfully loaded geoip database file [GeoLite2-Country.mmdb]
[2022-02-18T15:50:28,538][INFO ][o.e.i.g.DatabaseNodeService] [Yusufs-MBP.home] successfully loaded geoip database file [GeoLite2-ASN.mmdb]
[2022-02-18T15:50:30,072][INFO ][o.e.i.g.DatabaseNodeService] [Yusufs-MBP.home] successfully loaded geoip database file [GeoLite2-City.mmdb]
[2022-02-18T15:50:30,235][WARN ][o.e.x.s.t.n.SecurityNetty4HttpServerTransport] [Yusufs-MBP.home] received plaintext http traffic on an https channel, closing connection Netty4HttpChannel{localAddress=/127.0.0.1:9200, remoteAddress=/127.0.0.1:52260}
```

Answer (score 1):

## TLDR;

The graphic interface you are looking for is Kibana.
You are trying to access the `transport layer port` of Elasticsearch.

## To understand

Elasticsearch exposes 2 [ports by default](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/what-are-ports-9200-and-9300-used-for/238578):

- `9200` which is the [http api layer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html#http-settings)
- `9300` which is the [transport layer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html#transport-settings)

But **none** of those ports is going to serve html content.
Elasticsearch only exposes API, it is a backend server.

The interface for Elasticsearch is Kibana. You need to [install and set up Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/settings.html) to connect with the API layer of Elasticsearch.

For very basic setup just provide in the `kibana.yml` file

```yaml
elasticsearch.hosts: <address of the elastic server + api port>
```